# How to create a Mac bootable live Linux USB on Windows?

Tags: boot, usb, windows, live-usb, mac

Right, I'll get right to it.

How can I make a Linux Live USB on Windows, that I can use on a Mac.

In front of me, I have a Windows laptop, and a dropped Mac Book Pro that won't properly boot. I need the Live USB to see what's wrong with the Mac, but conventional methods won't work. Running Linux on VM on the Windows isn't really viable, as it's a very old laptop, and I can only do basic stuff on it.

The Live USB has to boot on the MAC.

Spec on Mac:
2.4GHz Intel Core i5
13.3 inch MacBook Pro
Model MD313X
Bought early 2012

Sort of in a rush...

Thank you!

Comment: In order to help you, can you please hit the **edit** below your question and give us more information [what kind of MacBook Pro](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4132) you are having in front of you?

Comment: Well, I added what I can. If you need anything else specific, please ask.

Comment: So this seems to be a MacBookPro8,1

Comment: It's not my MacBook. I don't know anything about Macs, and we really need this thing booting as quick as possible. Thanks if you can help!

Comment: @Jack This site is not the right place for urgent matters. And next time indicate what you've tried already, as this is a really basic question as far as I can see, which you can find answers for using the search.

Comment: Sorry. Where should I go?

Comment: Don't worry, I **don't** know really anything about MacBooks either ;-) What I know is, that it makes a difference if there is a Intel or PowerPC CPU in there. This was need to be able to suggest a ISO which will work. See my answer below.

Comment: In a comment on MadMike's answer you said you would try unetbootin, did that work?

Comment: Seth, sorry. It didn't really work. Macs are weird that way. Here's what did work: http://studyblast.wordpress.com/2011/08/14/guide-mac-os-x-lion-how-to-boot-a-linux-live-system-from-a-usb-drive-how-to-update-any-ocz-ssds-firmware/

Comment: @Jack when answering to someone comments, the best way is using `@` that way the get informed. Also that article is way too old but if it worked for you you are able to add that in the answers above.

Comment: @Braiam Thanks for the reminder. Since departing from C#, I haven't used SE in a long time. Forgot about the @. Also, I did add the answer below. I know it's really old, but at least it got me where I needed. For now.

Answer (score 1):

I personaly prefer the Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS release, you can download it [from this page](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/) and use it with [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) which allows you to create a bootable USB-Stick.

Good luck.

Comment: But unetbootin doesn't boot on mac does it?

Comment: Install Unetbootin on your Windows machine and create the USB-Stick from there. It will create a USB-Stick your MacBook will be able to boot from.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try now. Although I should ask whether I should be using the x86 or 64-bit version.

Comment: The 64-bit version will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Right. As for now, what worked for me was this:
http://studyblast.wordpress.com/2011/08/14/guide-mac-os-x-lion-how-to-boot-a-linux-live-system-from-a-usb-drive-how-to-update-any-ocz-ssds-firmware/

I got it to boot up to GRUB, but and I probably would have got to Ubuntu eventually, but I didn't bother because I already knew what was there to know.

Thanks everyone!