# Can you boot a mac with an empty harddrive using an UBUNTU iso from a usb written from a windows computer?

Tags: system-installation

I've just replaced the harddrive on my mac and was hoping to swap directly to UBUNTU as my OS. Can this be done? If so, can it be done from a usb written by a windows computer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a Mac bootable live Linux USB on Windows?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/360130/how-to-create-a-mac-bootable-live-linux-usb-on-windows)

Comment: This is not a good duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) utility, which runs on all three operating systems, creates a LiveUSB you can use on a Mac. Install Unetbootin on your Windows machine and create the USB-Stick from there. It will create a USB-Stick your MacBook will be able to boot from, as per Mad Mike [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360130/how-to-create-a-mac-bootable-live-linux-usb-on-windows).

Answer (score 0):

Please see: [How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows | Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

You will need to boot from the USB drive, then just install to the new HDD as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Well i'm not sure if you put Ubuntu directly into it and then boot it.
i suggest you create a bootable flashdisk from Windows then boot it on your mac.So *the installer can automatically configuring the hardware*

Some apps for creating Bootable Flashdisk from Windows

- [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)
- [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/)