# Live Linux USB to boot on a MAC but made on a PC?

Tags: boot, usb, windows-7, live-usb, mac

I'm trying to get more info on this subject.

[How to create a Mac bootable live Linux USB on Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360130/how-to-create-a-mac-bootable-live-linux-usb-on-windows)

I'm trying to create a bootable linux live USB that will work on a MAC (by holding the option/alt button down while booting)OSX Lion 10.7.something.  This USB must be created on a PC however. Windows 7 or 8, it doesn't matter which one I use.  The link I mention above does say to use UNetbootin yet in the second paragraph, under requirements, there is a blurb that the resulting USB will only be usable on PCs.

I'm a little new to the Linux community and I'm learning about EFI so my question is, is it a specific distro that would launch on both Windows and Macs as a live USB or what do i need to do to accomplish this task?

Bottom line is: I'm trying to help a co-worker recover files. I don't have a MAC myself nor access to one.  Virtual box with MAC software is also off the table.  Within my curriculum we are studying live boot USBs, so the challenge has been issued.

I don't know whether EFI is an issue or not. What process do I take to create this USB?

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to Post back with the answer to my own question.

It is quite possible.

Short answer: you need 2 things along with a windows OS installed on a comp.

- Rufus rufus.akeo.ie
- EFI Bootable Linux like Ubuntu 14.0 or higher http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

  - Must be for 64 bit OS (amd64)
    Choose GPT for the partition Scheme and FAT32 for the file system, in Rufus and create. This will work for MAC or for windows 8 computers like Surface Pro 1-3 (when modifying their boot order). Silly easy.

Long answer: a collection of information

It comes down to BIOS vs UEFI. (great link here https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Some_basics_of_MBR_v/s_GPT_and_BIOS_v/s_UEFI)

BIOS, using MBR partitioning scheme, is obviously used on windows 7 and earlier pc's, along with some Linux OS's as well.

GPT (GUID Partition Table), using UEFI which replaces BIOS, is used for MAC computers along with Windows 8 computers like Surface, Surface PRO, and others.

At the end of the day, the LIVE USB that was created worked on both Win8 and MAC computers as the partition scheme was the same. A second USB would be needed to live boot with computers that use MBR/BIOS.

Thanks to LiveWireBT for an answer. If only I'd checked it earlier it may have saved me all the research time!

And thanks all for letting me post here!

Comment: And please, if there is more that anyone can add to this (or correct me if needed) do so, for the sake of correct information.

Comment: Thanks, I was helped with your research!

Answer (score 1):

Answers suggesting UNetbootin are mostly misleading. While it is correct that Ubuntu Mac images use or setup BIOS emulation on Macs, UNetbootin is only for booting legacy PCs.

I don't have much experience with Macs either but the following answer might help you booting Macs with EFI: [Can I make a bootable USB flash drive for Mac from Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131562/can-i-make-a-bootable-usb-flash-drive-for-mac-from-windows/548741#548741)